# How to create test class with Case Attachment and send email?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am looking to developed the test class for the following code. How we can write class for the following code?

Actually when below trigger executes it send Case Attachments (present in attachment section) in email to Legal team

```
trigger sendEAttachmentsInMail on Case (before insert, before update){

for(Case casevar : Trigger.new){

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setBccSender(false);
        mail.setUseSignature(false);
        mail.setTargetObjectId(casevar.Id);
        mail.setTemplateId('XXXXXXXXX');
        mail.saveAsActivity = false;

      //Set email file attachments
        List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();
        for (Attachment a : [select Name, Body, BodyLength from Attachment where ParentId = :casevar.Id])
        {
        // Add to attachment file list
        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
        efa.setFileName(a.Name);
        efa.setBody(a.Body);
        fileAttachments.add(efa);
        }
        mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
      //Send email
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });     
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it on your own. If you get stuck then post your test class. I'm sure community will help you.